# Use *ngFor for JSON object with nested arrays

Tags: html, angular

I I have a JSON object that has several levels of nest objects as well as nested arrays of objects. I would like to know how to use Angular2 and *ngFor to iterate through the object and end up with the listed printed out. The first *ngFor works but the next *ngFor give me and error saying `Cannot read property nodes of undefined`

Current HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
               <div>
                    <ol>
                         <li *ngFor="let item of videoList" > {{item.title}} </li>
                         <ol>
                              <li *ngFor="let subItem of videoList.item.nodes"> {{subItem.title}} </li>
                         </ol>
                    </ol>
               </div>
         </div>
```

JSON object

```
  videoList =  [
          {
               'id':1,
               'title':'Lower Extremities',
               'nodes':[
                    {
                         'id':11,
                         'title':'Cast Receive',
                         'nodes':[
                                   {
                                   'id':111,
                                   'title':'Video 1',
                                   'nodes':[
                                             {
                                             'id':1111,
                                             'title':'Working',
                                             'nodes':[]
                                             },
                                             {
                                             'id':1112,
                                             'title':'Stacking',
                                             'nodes':[]
                                             },
                                        ]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':112,
                                   'title':'Video 2',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':113,
                                   'title':'Video 3',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              }
                         ]
                    },
                     {
                         'id':12,
                         'title':'Cast Inspection',
                         'nodes':[
                              {
                                   'id':121,
                                   'title':'Video 1',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':122,
                                   'title':'Video 2',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':123,
                                   'title':'Video 3',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              }
                         ]
                    },
                     {
                         'id':13,
                         'title':'Cut & Set',
                         'nodes':[
                              {
                                   'id':131,
                                   'title':'Video 1',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':132,
                                   'title':'Video 2',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              },
                              {
                                   'id':133,
                                   'title':'Video 3',
                                   'nodes':[]
                              }
                         ]
                    }
               ]
          }
```

**EDIT**
I attempted the given answer and all I recieved was a list of numbers 1, 2, and 3. Here is what I did.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <ol>
           <li *ngFor="let item of videoList" > {{item.title}} </li>
           <ol>
                <li *ngFor="let subItem of item['nodes']" > {{subItem.title}} </li>
           </ol>
      </ol>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

videoList = [
    {
      'id':1,
      'title':'Lower Extremities',
      'nodes': [
          {
            'id':11,
            'title':'Second node',
            'nodes': "[]"
          },
          {
            'id':12,
            'title':'Second node',
            'nodes': "[]"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      'id':2,
      'title':'Second node',
      'nodes': []
    },
    {
      'id':3,
      'title':'third node',
      'nodes': []
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: Your question inspired me to a solution to a big problem in my angular project thanks @Per Larsen!

Answer (score 11):

The second `for` loop should be

```
 <li *ngFor="let subItem of item['nodes']"> {{subItem.title}} </li>
```

Comment: and would every subsequent for loop refer to the nodes attribute in the same way. For instance `li *ngFor = "let subSubItem of subItem['nodes']"`?

Comment: Yes, it should, just follow the json tree

Answer (score 11):

The problem I was having was I was not nesting the successive `<li>` elements properly in the previous `<li>` tags. Here is how it should have been.

```html
       <div>
            <ol>
                 <li *ngFor="let item of videoList" > 
                      <div>{{item.title}}</div> 
                      <ol>
                           <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.nodes"> 
                                <div>{{subItem.title}}</div> 
                           </li>
                      </ol>
                 </li>
            </ol>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <li *ngFor="let subItem of item['nodes']">

 {{subItem.title}} </li>

//Instead of item['nodes'] try item.nodes

 <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.nodes"> {{subItem.title}} </li>

//its perfectly working fine for me ! cheers !
```