# Retrieving an object from an array inside an object using *ngfor IONIC and JSON

Tags: json, ionic-framework, nested, ngfor

I'm struggling retrieving an object from inside an array that's nested in an object in a json file.

The Json file is this:

```
    {
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "You can’t succeed coming to the potluck with only a fork.",
                "author": "Dave Liniger",
                "length": "64",
                "tags": [
                    "inspire",
                    "team-building",
                    "tso-funny",
                    "working-with-people"
                ],
                "category": "inspire",
                "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day",
                "date": "2018-05-05",
                "id": null
            }
        ],
        "copyright": "2017-19 theysaidso.com"
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the quote nested in quotes.

So far I have been trying this:

```
    <ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of contents"></ion-item>
<ion-item *ngFor="let q of c['quotes']">
    <h2>{{ q.quote }}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

However I keep getting "unable to get property of 'quotes' of undefined or null reference"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can not directly access the contents of json file using ngFor

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I do have access. I am using a provider 'quote.ts' . This returns the contents of the json to me

Comment: You are trying to access c outside the scope of ngFor   <ion-item *ngFor="let c of contents"><ion-item *ngFor="let q of c['quotes']">
    <h2>{{ q.quote }}</h2>
</ion-item></ion-item>

Comment: How can I access the array "quotes" inside of "contents" then?

Comment: I have tried this:  <ion-item *ngFor="let q of quotes"{{contents}}>
  <h2>{{ q.quote }}</h2>

Comment: But i get no output displayed for the quote

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
    <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let q of contents.quotes">
        <h2>{{ q.quote }}</h2>

    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

See the following example for nested **ngFor**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngfor-grouped-example',
  template: `
 <h4>NgFor (grouped)</h4>
 <ul *ngFor="let group of peopleByCountry"> 
   <li>{{ group.country }}</li>
   <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of group.people"> 
      {{ person.name }}
    </li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
 `
})
class NgForGroupedExampleComponent {

  peopleByCountry: any[] = [
    {
      'country': 'UK',
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Douglas  Pace"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mcleod  Mueller"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': 'US',
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Day  Meyers"
        },
        {
          "name": "Aguirre  Ellis"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cook  Tyson"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

You can also refer to this link for more details:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but am getting "cannot find a differ supporting object '(Object Object)' of type 'Object' NgFor only supports binding to iterables such as arrays?

Comment: Try this I have updated the answer,I missed that contents is an object in your json

Comment: Thanks. I got "Unable to get property 'quotes' of undefined or null reference?

Comment: Can you share your controller code, have you assigned your response to any variable?

Comment: It won't let me, too many characters. I have declared a quotes string array in my home.ts( quotes: string[]). Then this is my quote.ts @Injectable()
export class QuoteProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello QuoteProvider Provider');
  }
   getQuote(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get("http://quotes.rest/qod.json");
 }

}

Comment: You need to map your response to a variable only then you can access it in your view

Comment: I have a qp variable in my home.ts ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.qp.getQuote().subscribe(data => {
    this.contents = data.contents;
    this.quotes = data.quotes;
   })
  }

Comment: Change quotes:  string[] to quotes: any[]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how it is wrong. I'm new to this

Comment: You are trying to access quotes which is nested in contents object

Comment: Yeah this has what has confused me from the start. I tried using the logic from the following link but still couldn't get mine working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110614/us-ngfor-for-json-object-with-nested-arrays

Comment: put console.log(this.contents) and tell me what are you getting?

Comment: I just get 'undefined'

Comment: put console.log(data) and tell me if you are still getting undefined

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: 'data' is not defined ReferenceError: 'data' is not defined at HomePage (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:191:9) at createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12817:13) at createDirectiveInstance

Comment: (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12658:5) at createViewNodes (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14116:21) at createRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14005:5) at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15430:9) at debugCreateRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14713:5) at ComponentFactory_.prototype.create (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11610:9) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4397:9) at NavControllerBase.prototype._viewInit (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51855:9)

Comment: It seems the issue is with your code of requesting data from server, please refer to this link https://angular.io/api/http/Http

Comment: Thanks. Had a look at that but now back to ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'quotes' of undefined or null reference TypeError: Unable to get property 'quotes' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function

Comment: Got it! Removed any reference to contents and added in this.quotes = data.contents.quotes;